# Transient is never set. Why?

Tags: transient

In one page, I try to set/get two transients. The second works fine. The first doesn't work at all. I can not figure out why.

Here's the relevant code.

```
    $lat = round($toReturn["location"]["coords"]["latitude"]);
    $long = round($toReturn["location"]["coords"]["longitude"]);
    
    $nearbyLocations = [function that gets nearby locations];

    $args = array(
        "post_type"         => "any",
        "posts_per_page"    => -1,
    );
    
    $mq["relation"] = "OR";

    foreach($nearbyLocations as $nl) {
        $mq[] = array(
            'key'       => 'location',
            'value'     => '"'.$nl["post_id"].'"',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        );
    }
    $args["meta_query"] = $mq;
    
    $transient_identifier = "nearme_sites_".$lat."_".$long;
    
    if ( false === ( $impact_query = get_transient( $transient_identifier ) ) ) {
        //This transient is never set
        $impact_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        set_transient( $transient_identifier, $impact_query, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    //I do something with the result of $impact_query
    
    $nearbyLocations = [Function that gets nearby locations of a type]
    
    $args = array(
        "post_type"         => "place",
        "posts_per_page"    => -1,
        "orderby"           => "post_title",
        "order"             => "ASC",
        "post__in"          => array_column($nearbyLocations, 'post_id')
    );

    $transient_identifier = "nearme_place_".$lat."_".$long;
    if ( false === ( $impact_query = get_transient( $transient_identifier ) ) ) {
        //This transient is set, as expected
        $impact_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        set_transient( $transient_identifier, $impact_query, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }
```

For a fixed lat/long, the first transient is never set, the second is set as expected.

Any thoughts as to why?

Update: it seems that if I do not include a meta_query in my arguments, the transient *does* work. So, it's not possible to use a transient when the arguments includes a meta_query?

Comment: maybe is your meta_query that isnt well formed,  you are using $mq[ ] inside the foreach, this said, each loop is making a new mq[ ] with no name inside the [ ], I dont even know if this can be done in php. try to see that, maybe is your meta_query that isnt being well formed.

Comment: Thanks. The meta query works as expected if I don't throw it in the transient. But, it's also a very long meta query ($nearbyLocations can be an array of a few hundred locations). So, I *suspect* there's some limit to the query that can be handled by a transient, but I can't find anything on this.